# Python script isn't working after converting it into a .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, pyinstaller

.exe:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from re import findall
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import subprocess
import time
from tkinter import ttk

status = False
path = "C:\\Users\\Koliferrr\\Desktop\\AutoShutdown_old"
class App: 
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    master.title("Shutdown Workstations")
    master.geometry("700x410")
    master.config(bg='grey82')
    # Create the options
    self.var1 = tk.BooleanVar()
    self.var2 = tk.BooleanVar()
    self.var3 = tk.BooleanVar()
    self.var4 = tk.BooleanVar()
    self.var5 = tk.BooleanVar()

    l = tk.Label(master, text = "Shutdown Workstations", font=("Arial", 16),bg='grey82')
    l.pack(pady=(10,10))
    separator2 = tk.Frame(master, bd=10, relief='sunken', height=8)
    separator2.pack(side='top', fill='x')
    # Create Read all button
    self.rabtn = tk.Button(master, text="Read all",command = self.rabtn, font=("Arial", 12))
        
    self.rabtn.pack(pady=(10,10))
    
    # Create the checkboxes and buttons
    self.frame1 = tk.Frame(master,bg='grey52',pady=(5), highlightbackground="grey40", highlightthickness=2)
    self.check1 = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame1, text="Printer Storage", variable=self.var1, font=("Arial", 14),bg='grey52',width=24)
    self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame1, text="    ", state=tk.DISABLED)
    self.frame1.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.check1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    self.button1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(0,10))

    self.frame2 = tk.Frame(master,bg='grey52',pady=(5), highlightbackground="grey40", highlightthickness=2)
    self.check2 = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame2, text="Gui Workstation", variable=self.var2, font=("Arial", 14),bg='grey52',width=24)
    self.button2 = tk.Button(self.frame2, text="    ", state=tk.DISABLED)
    self.frame2.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.check2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    self.button2.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(0,10))

    self.frame3 = tk.Frame(master,bg='grey52',pady=(5), highlightbackground="grey40", highlightthickness=2)
    self.check3 = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame3, text="Render Satellite Workstation", variable=self.var3, font=("Arial", 14),bg='grey52',width=24)
    self.button3 = tk.Button(self.frame3, text="    ", state=tk.DISABLED)
    self.frame3.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.check3.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    self.button3.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(0,10))
        
    self.frame4 = tk.Frame(master,bg='grey52',pady=(5), highlightbackground="grey40", highlightthickness=2)
    self.check4 = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame4, text="TuneIn Workstation", variable=self.var4, font=("Arial", 14),bg='grey52',width=24)
    self.button4 = tk.Button(self.frame4, text="    ", state=tk.DISABLED)
    self.frame4.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.check4.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    self.button4.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(0,10))

    self.frame5 = tk.Frame(master,bg='grey52',pady=(5), highlightbackground="grey40", highlightthickness=2)
    self.check5 = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame5, text="All Workstations", variable=self.var5, font=("Arial", 14),bg='grey52',width=27)
    
    self.frame5.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.check5.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
   

    # Create the submit button
    self.submit_button = tk.Button(master, text="Shutdown", command=self.submit, font=("Arial", 14),width=15)
    self.submit_button.pack(pady=(10,10))
    
def askshutdown(self):
    msg_box = tk.messagebox.askquestion('Shutdown', 'Do you really want to shutdown the Workstation?', icon='warning')
    if msg_box == 'yes':
        root.quit()
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Info', "Workstation will be shut down")
    else:
        self.resetcheckbtn()
        root.quit()
        
def submit(self):
    if (self.var1.get() and self.var5.get()) or (self.var2.get() and self.var5.get()) or (self.var3.get() and self.var5.get()) or (self.var4.get() and self.var5.get()):
        tk.messagebox.showwarning('Warning', "Please don't select All Workstations and another Option")
    else:
        if not self.var1.get() and not self.var2.get() and not self.var3.get() and not self.var4.get() and not self.var5.get():
            tk.messagebox.showwarning('Warning', "Please select something")
            return None
        self.askshutdown()
        
        # Check which options are selected
        if self.var1.get():
            print("1")
            subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\\Koliferrr\\AutoShutdown_old\\test.bat'], shell=False)
            #subprocess.call(['c:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\AutoShutdown\\PrinterStorageShutdown.bat'])     
        if self.var2.get():
            print("2")
            #subprocess.call(['c:\\Users\Admin\\Documents\\AutoShutdown\\WindowsGUIShutdown.bat'])     
        if self.var3.get():
            print("3")
            #subprocess.call(['c:\\Users\Admin\\Documents\\AutoShutdown\\RenderSatelitShutdown.bat'])     
        if self.var4.get():
            print("4")
            #subprocess.call(['c:\\Users\Admin\\Documents\\AutoShutdown\\TuneInShutdown.bat'])     
        if self.var5.get():
            print("5")
            #subprocess.call(['c:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\AutoShutdown\\ShutdownallWorkstations.bat'])
        self.resetcheckbtn()
                               
def rabtn(self):
    self.resetcheckbtn()
    nodes = ["10.10.110.122","10.0.0.99","10.0.0.101","192.168.137.97","10.0.0.170"]
    self.ping(nodes,3)

def resetcheckbtn(self):
    self.var1.set(0)
    self.var2.set(0)
    self.var3.set(0)
    self.var4.set(0)
    self.var5.set(0)

    return

def ping(self,host,ping_count):
    self.master.config(cursor="wait")
    self.master.update()
    self.rabtn.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    status=False
    for ip in host:
        data = ""
        output= Popen(f"ping {ip} -n {ping_count}", stdout=PIPE, encoding="latin-1",creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
        for line in output.stdout:
            data = data + line
            ping_test = findall("TTL", data)
        print(data)
        if ping_test:
            status= True
            self.editstate(ip,status)
            
        if not ping_test:
            status = False
            self.editstate(ip,status)
    self.rabtn.config(state=tk.NORMAL) 
    self.master.config(cursor="")
    self.master.update()
    
def editstate(self,ip,status):
    print(ip,status)
    if(ip=="10.10.110.122" and status==True):
        self.button1.config(bg='green')
    elif(ip=="10.10.110.122" and status==False):
        self.button1.config(bg='red')
    #if(ip=="10.0.0.99" and status==True):
        #self.button1.config(bg='green')
    #elif(ip=="10.0.0.99" and status==False):
        #self.button1.config(bg='red')
        
    if(ip=="10.0.0.101" and status==True):
        self.button2.config(bg='green')
    elif(ip=="10.0.0.101" and status==False):
        self.button2.config(bg='red')
        
    if(ip=="192.168.137.97" and status==True):
        self.button3.config(bg='green')
    elif(ip=="192.168.137.97" and status==False):
        self.button3.config(bg='red')
        
    if(ip=="10.0.0.170" and status==True):
        self.button4.config(bg='green')
    elif(ip=="10.0.0.170" and status==False):
        self.button4.config(bg='red')
    
       
root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

test.bat:

```
ping 10.10.110.122
```

the test.bat is just to test it

I currently made a small program with python where I call some .bat files that execute something in the cmd. If I run this .py file everything works fine. But as if I converted it with `pyinstaller` into a .exe the .bat files are getting called but everything closes itself after seconds. So to say the .bat files aren't executed correctly.
Here is the part where I call the .bat files:

```
subprocess.call(['path_to_file'])
```

I would be grateful if someone could get up with some solution.

I already tried to call the .bat files in multiple ways as:

```
os.system...
subprocess.Popen
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you call your exe from cmd or do you double-click it in explorer?

Comment: It's meant to be double clicked

Comment: I'd assume that `os.chdir()` would help. Alternatively, define the working directory in the 'secret' batch file or better yet, always use fully qualified absolute paths.

Comment: I tired it with os.chdir() but it changed nothing. My .bat files are in another directory so from the beginning I always used the absolute path. I guess the .bat is getting called but isn't executed

Comment: Please try running the created *.exe from cmd line to see any possible output. Is there anything? If not .. Why do you think that the ".bat files are getting called" ?

Comment: I ran it form the cmd line. There was no output. If I cone to the point where the .bat file is getting called an empty cmd is being opened and after a few second it gets closed witout any change